# Codeigniter not espacing post data on insert

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, post, escaping

Trying to insert random emails like test''@test.com, etc.. and they are inserted into the database. Shouldn't this be automatically prevented by Active Record?

My query:

```
$data = array(
  'name' => ''.$name.'' ,
  'email' => ''.$email.'' ,
  'country' => ''.$country.'' ,
  'phone' => ''.$phone.'' ,
  'compid' => ''.$compID.'' 
);

$this->db->insert('people', $data);
```

Where all variables are taken from user POST input, such as

`$this->input->post('address')`

for address.

Comment: Why you add single quotes before variables?

Comment: You're right, not sure why. I've tried also without single quotes now, and the email ''''@adfadf.com was successfully inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this be:

```
$data = array(
  'name' => $name,
  'email' => $email,
  'country' => $country,
  'phone' => $phone,
  'compid' => $compID
);

$this->db->insert('people', $data);
```